# Selenium HtmlUnitDriver compiled javascript mode

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0, rhino, selenium-webdriver

I am using the HtmlUnitDriver in a play app (play.api.test.TestBrowser.webDriver is an instance of the HtmlUnitDriver) to test user interactions. I have a JavaSrcipt file that defines some functions after they have been used. That doesn't cause problems in browsers, but does in the driver. The driver complains, that the function 'x' doesn't exist.

As I read about the HtmlUnitDriver I found out that it is using the Rhino (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) JavaScript interpreter. It seems like it works in the interpreter rather than compile mode, causing this type of problems.

Is it a way to tell HtmlUnitDriver to work with Rhino in compiled JavaScript mode? I would still like to use HtmlUnitDriver rather than GUI version like Firefox.

Could it be done using some system properties, config files etc?